# Aptana Code Folding?

Tags: aptana, code-folding

When i try to use code folding in Aptana it doesn't seem to be working i haven't changed any shortcuts and i can`t get it work the default shortcut is Ctrl+Numpad_Divide any suggestions ?

Answer (score 9):

Ctrl+Shift+Numpad_Divide will work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you (accidentaly) disable code folding in Aptana?

Check it in Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors -> Enable folding.

You should check your key bindings, too:

Preferences -> General -> Keys -> Toggle Folding

Do you have another application interfering with your hotkey configuration? Have you installed new programs recently?

Comment: Folding is enabled and i tried many key configurations with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I guess the relevant question back is: what file types are you expecting folding on that you aren't getting it for? And what version of Aptana are we talking about: 2.x or 3.x?

We offer folding on Javascript, CSS, Ruby, PHP, XML, HTML across both versions. It would be helpful to know what file you're dealing with, and what code you expect to be able to be folded that isn't offering you that option.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's html. I once had it running, now it's gone again. Never worked well, though.
I don't have a section "Structured Text Editors" (v3.0.6)
Edit: actually, it's php and I now found it here: Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors > PHP. 
I already had it enabled, and eventually found these little blue icons for folding in odd places. Sometimes they work as expected, sometimes they don't. They're only in the top few lines of my document, then no more (stops at line 86 of 864).

Answer (score 0):

First - as far as I can tell it only works with recent versions of Eclipse - i.e. version 4.4+ (Luna).

Second - it's enabled by default, but can be toggled in the language-specific editor settings. Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors > [Language: PHP, Ruby, etc.]

Third - if there is a syntax error in the code bracketing - e.g. a missing `}` or `end` it often breaks all of the code folding in the whole file. This is pretty annoying because in other errors, code folding is useful for finding  such errors.